# Connect Server C#

Tags: c#, server

How do you connect to a server in C# WPF with the host, login and password ?
For example, I have a button and when I click on this button, it connects to a server.

Thanks.

Comment: What type of server? Database server? Which database? Specify a little more.

Comment: Searching instead of asking should be your first thought

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is not clear at all, please state clearly, what you want to achieve, what you have tried so far, if you faced any issues. Also, have a look at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using `TcpClient` class. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1415/Introduction-to-TCP-client-server-in-C) an example.

Comment: What if he is talking about, say, shared memory server?

Comment: The question does not provide anywhere near enough information to be answered at this point.